# How do I remove a dot from a specific string?

Tags: c#, string

```
    Console.WriteLine("Write three words with a point in the end");

    var ord = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    string a = ord[0];
    string b = ord[1];
    string c = ord[2];

    Console.WriteLine(c+" "+b+" "+a+".")
```

So what I am trying to do is have these three words (a,b,c) in oppisite order and with a dot in the end. So Im trying to reomve the dot after string c and then add one after a. But can't figure out how.

Comment: I tried this: string clean = c.Replace(".", string.Empty);

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: I am using c# as coding language

Comment: Can you be more precise? The strings will always be in the same format with the dot at the end? Then you can just delete the last character of the string. If it's not the case and the dot could be anywhere in the middle, you can seek for that dot and remove it. Mind you that your solution will remove EVERY dot present in the string, not just the last one.

Comment: the problem is the when i type my three words for exempel "sun red blue." i get "blue. red sun." i want it to remove the dot after blue and the add a dot after sun so its "blue red sun."

Comment: so the thing is that i want to remove a dot that is in the middle of the three words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Trim the dot before splitting:

   ```
   var ord = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd('.').Split(' ');
   ```
2. Use the same variable instead of a new one (`clean`)

   ```
   c = c.TrimEnd('.')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close:

- you're splitting the sentence into an array of words
- you're selecting the first three array elements (first three words)
- you're printing the three words in reverse order, and concatenating a period

The only step that's missing is removing the `.` from the end of the user's input.  That can be done in several ways:

The sample of what you tried looks like it should work -- perhaps you forgot to update your `Console.WriteLine()` call to use `clean` instead of `c`?

```cs
string clean = c.Replace('.', string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(clean + " " + b + " " + a + ".");
```

Removing the last character from `ord` prior to splitting it is another option, something like:

```cs
var noDot = ord.Substring(0, ord.Length - 1);
// (and then splitting `noDot`)
```

Or removing all `.`'s from the input:

```cs
var ord = Console.ReadLine().Replace('.', string.Empty).Split(' ');
```

And you could also exploring doing this declaratively with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

```cs
string input = "one two three four.";
var reversedThree = input.Replace(".", string.Empty).Split(' ').AsQueryable().Take(3).Reverse();
Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" ", reversedThree)}.");
```